# Display random records from MySQL table individually using setInterval

Tags: jquery, mysql

I wish to display 5 sentences every second. The following code works when I list each sentence in the RandomSentences variable:

```
(function() {
var timesRun = 0;
var runLimit = 5;
var RandomSentences = ['This is the first sentence', 'This is the second sentence', 'This is the third sentence', 'This is the fourth sentence', 'This is the fifth sentence'],
i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
timesRun += 1;
if (timesRun < runLimit) {

  $('#changing-word').fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).html(RandomSentences[i = (i + 1) % RandomSentences.length]).fadeIn();
  });
 }
}, 1000);

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="changing-word">Sentences go here</span>
```

However, I have a table of thousands of sentences and I would like 5 random ones to be displayed. I can select these records like this:

```
SELECT sentences FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

But now how do I put these 5 random records into the RandomSentences variable so I can go ahead and display them each second using the setInterval above?

Comment: jquery does not directly work with mysql. You need a server-side page/code to transfer values from mysql to jquery like php, asp, jsp, node etc. What server-side script are you using?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this with PHP?

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp